C macro expand to different function based on different types
I'm trying to do this in C:

create an interface with 3 arguments
expand it to calling different function based on the first argument:


if is integer then call bar1 with 2nd/3rd arguments
if is float then call bar2 with 2nd/3rd arguments but reversed order

The issue here is that the argument list of bar1 and bar2 are not compatible, like this:
struct node1 { int aa; };
struct node2 { int bb; };

extern void bar1(int, struct node1);
extern void bar2(struct node2, int);

// How to define macro for mycall?

void foo() {
    int a, b;
    float f;
    struct node1 n1;
    struct node2 n2;

    mycall(a, b, n1);
    mycall(f, b, n2);
}

May I ask is there ever a way to achieve this in C during compile time (I don't want if(typeof) in my case)? Thanks!
More clearly, I want mycall(a, b, n1) to be expand to bar1(b, n1) and mycall(f, b, n2) to be expand to bar2(n2, b).
My trial:
I tried to use _Generic like this:
#define get_1st_arg(x, y) (x)
#define get_2nd_arg(x, y) (y)

#define mycall(x, op1, op2) _Generic((x), \
  int: bar1(op1, op2), \
  float: bar2(op2, op1) \
)

However I got compilation error like this:
test.c: In function ‘foo’:
test.c:23:15: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘bar2’
   23 |  mycall(a, b, n1);
      |               ^~
      |               |
      |               struct node1
test.c:14:15: note: in definition of macro ‘mycall’
   14 |   float: bar2(op2, op1) \
      |               ^~~
test.c:5:18: note: expected ‘struct node2’ but argument is of type ‘struct node1’
    5 | extern void bar2(struct node2, int);
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:24:15: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘bar1’
   24 |  mycall(f, b, n2);
      |               ^~
      |               |
      |               struct node2
test.c:13:18: note: in definition of macro ‘mycall’
   13 |   int: bar1(op1, op2), \
      |                  ^~~
test.c:4:23: note: expected ‘struct node1’ but argument is of type ‘struct node2’
    4 | extern void bar1(int, struct node1);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~

looks like it still try to compile bar2 even if the first operand is integer, which means it tries to check bar2(n1, b) and thus fails.

Why have you added C++ tags? Are you compiling C code with a C++ compiler? typedef struct {} node1; isn't valid C but iirc that's valid C++.

C and C++ are two very different languages. To begin with, this should not be handled by macros in C++. Not to mention that C++ doesn't have _Generic.

apologize for confusing, it's C only. I have updated the tag and description

What is the benefit of writing mycall() twice when you actually want to call two different functions?  The macro seems to be a mechanism for obfuscating straightforward code.

The bast way is to change language. C does not have polymorphism

The problem is that when you put _Generic inside a macro, then each item in the association list is expanded for the given macro parameters. And not just the item that matches.
Normally you would solve this by having _Generic expand just to the function name and leave the function parameters outside _Generic, so that they won't get expanded for the irrelevant parts of the list. But now you also want to swap arguments depending on function picked, so that's not an option either.
It's such a mess because the function API itself is very bad and ought to be rewritten. If that is not a possibility because you are maintaining some old code rot, then the least bad thing you can do is to come up with a wrapper function that performs the argument swapping:
extern void bar1 (int, node1);
extern void bar2 (node2, int);
static void bar2_wrapper (int i, node2 n2)
{
  bar2(n2, i);
}

#define mycall(x, op1, op2)     \
  _Generic((x),                 \
           int:   bar1,         \
           float: bar2_wrapper  \
          ) (op1, op2)


It's sad that using function wrapper in my case will raise another issue, but still thank you!

@user26966001 Why is that?

It's actually an issue I found in adding a clang/llvm builtin, related here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78906419/pass-an-immediate-from-clang-frontend-to-llvm-intrinsic-with-o0

@user26966001, when you find yourself fighting so hard against the language, you should probably take two steps back and reconsider your approach.  Your other question raises red flags for me all by itself, and if it's causing additional trouble for you then I've gotta think there are better ways of doing what you want to do.

Simply select the parts of the expression individually with _Generic:
#define mycall(x, op1, op2)                \
    _Generic(x, int: bar1, float: bar2)    \
    (                                      \
        _Generic(x, int: op1, float: op2), \
        _Generic(x, int: op2, float: op1)  \
    )

or you might prefer:
#define G(x, y, z) _Generic(x, int: y, float: z)
#define mycall(x, op1, op2) G(x, bar1, bar2) (G(x, op1, op2), G(x, op2, op1))


This is exactly what I want and it works for me! Thanks
